# how to convert from base64 to string by hand

Tags: encoding, base64

I am looking for some steps to follow to convert a base64 password to string by hand, but the only thing I find is online-tools to decrypt-encrypt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://www.base64encode.org/

they have an explanation at the bottom. you could also read the rfc 4648:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648

You probably need to know all the ascii codes for the characters you want to encode, then how to get the bits and so on ..

Also it is 3x8 bits that create 4x6 bits, so you might learn the direct conversion for all 3/4 positions if you are nerdy enough. :)

cool question, always wondered how it's done but never really checked, thx!

Comment: lol, a little googling would have gone a long way too ;) good luck!